# Why is sort -k not working all the time?

Tags: bash

I have now a script that puts a list of files in two separate arrays:

First, I get a file list from a ZIP file and fill `FIRST_Array()` with it. Second, I get a file list from a control file within a ZIP file and fill `SECOND_Array()` with it

```
while read length date time filename 
do
    FIRST_Array+=( "$filename" )
    echo "$filename" >> FIRST.report.out
done < <(/usr/bin/unzip -qql AAA.ZIP |sort -g -k12 -t~)
```

Third, I compare both array like so:

```
diff -q <(printf "%s\n" "${FIRST_Array[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${SECOND_Array[@]}") |wc -l
```

I can tell that  `Diff` fails because I output each array to files: `FIRST.report.out` and `SECOND.report.out` are simply  not sorted properly.

1) FIRST.report.out (what's inside the ZIP file)

`JGS-Memphis~AT1~Pre-Test~X-BanhT~JGMDTV387~6~P~1100~HR24-500~033072053326~20120808~240914.XML
JGS-Memphis~PRE~DTV_PREP~X-GuinE~JGMDTV069~6~P~1100~H24-700~033081107519~20120808~240914.XML
JGS-Memphis~PRE~DTV_PREP~X-MooreBe~JGM98745~40~P~1100~H21-200~029264526103~20120808~240914.XML
JGS-Memphis~FUN~Pre-Test~X-RossA~jgmdtv168~2~P~1100~H21-200~029415655926~20120808~240914.XML`

2) SECOND.report.out (what's inside the ZIP's control file)

`JGS-Memphis~AT1~Pre-Test~X-BanhT~JGMDTV387~6~P~1100~HR24-500~033072053326~20120808~240914.XML
JGS-Memphis~FUN~Pre-Test~X-RossA~jgmdtv168~2~P~1100~H21-200~029415655926~20120808~240914.XML
JGS-Memphis~PRE~DTV_PREP~X-GuinE~JGMDTV069~6~P~1100~H24-700~033081107519~20120808~240914.XML
JGS-Memphis~PRE~DTV_PREP~X-MooreBe~JGM98745~40~P~1100~H21-200~029264526103~20120808~240914.XML`

Using `sort -k12 -t~` made sense since `~` is the delimiter for the file's date field (12th position). But it is not working consistently. Added `-g` made no difference.

The sort is worse when my script processes bigger ZIP files. Why is sort -k not working all the time? How can I sort both arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't really have a k12 in your data, your separator is '~' in your spec, but you have ~ and sometimes - in your data.

you can check by

```
head -n 1 your.data.file |  sed -e "s/~/\n/g"
```

Comment: What would you suggest for a sort criteria then? Can I have more than one delimiter in my sort -t?

Comment: are you sorting the field that contains "033072053326" ? that field is actually k10

Comment: The field that contains "20120808" is what I am sorting on: 12th position from the left, assuming that you take the "~" as delimiter.

Comment: changed to k11. No difference

Comment: I notice your sample data has identical data on that field, so it sort won't work. You must have data that are different, no?

Comment: I wonder what kind of output is produced by /usr/bin/unzip -qql AAA.ZIP? I notice it produce a format that is space/column delimited here.

Comment: The output produced is what you see in `FIRST.report.out`. Unsorted.

Comment: I need to revise my strategy on the sort issue. I am going to close this thread. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Business requirements are going to be changed. Sort is no longer required in this case. Thread can closed. Thank you.